# Differences between "vorgehen" and "vorangehen" in the sense of "move forward"

Tags: word-formation

I am trying to figure out the difference between *vorgehen* and *vorangehen*.

From the perspective of word-formation, both denote the sense of "to move forward".

From Langenscheidt Großwörterbuch, *vorgehen* means

> (of people) take steps forward/take measures

and *vorangehen* means

> (von Sache) progress

I am wondering whether this difference in word meaning and usage may be traced back to the difference between the difference between the two prefixes *vor-* and *voran-*? If the answer be yes, how to interpret *voran-* in terms of the combination of *vor-* and *an-*?

(the following content is a later addition to the original post)
I risk this wild guess that *voran|gehen* means *moving in an expected direction*; the notion *in an anticipatory direction* may be what *an* denotes and what is absent from *vorgehen*.
Would any one agree or disagree with my guess?

Comment: Are you aware that "vorangehen" has more meanings, besides the one you mentioned? In fact, same is true for *vorgehen*.

Comment: @Em1 : thanks for your attention; yes, there are other designations of the two; yet I'd like to concentrate on the particular senses mentioned in the post; are you suggesting that a wholistic approach would be more appropriate to this question?

Comment: Additions to questions after answers have been given [are not well received](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/903).

Comment: @Jan : thanks for your notification; should I post this question anew in order that it get well received?

Comment: I don’t think that your addendum is ‘substantial’ enough for a site question. Why not try out the [chat]?

Answer (score 4):

*Vorangehen*, in the context of personal movement, means to go as the first in line (others follow directly behind).

Example:

> Ich gehe voran, weil ich als einziger den Weg kenne.

*Vorgehen*, in the context of personal movement, means to go before the others go (others follow later).

Example:

> Ich gehe vor und kaufe die Tickets, ihr wartet hier auf den Rest der Gruppe.

Comment: Wenn ich den Gasmann in den Keller zum Zähler führe, sage ich "ich geh' mal vor'", erwarte aber schon, dass der Gasmann direkt nachkommt...

Comment: Wie so oft entzieht sich auch hier der alltägliche Sprachgebrauch einer absolut gültigen Definition. Möglicherweise gibt es da auch regionale Unterschiede, ich bin aus Wien.

Comment: Ich denke eher, dass man *vorangeht*, wenn man gemeinsam mit einer Gruppe unterwegs ist, und *vorgeht*, wenn man mit jemandem unterwegs ist, mit dem man keine Gruppe bildet. Das wäre *nahe* an deiner Erklärung, aber nicht genau dasselbe (Weil man von einer Gruppe, mit der ich unterwegs bin, ja erwarten würde, dass die direkt nachkommt). "Wissen" tu ich das aber nicht.